# Snap Geometries to Layer unexpected behavior

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, snapping

I have been trying to snap points to a line layer (**vertex or segment**)
but the "Snap Geometries to Layer" processing algorithm with behavior 3 supposed to do what I want

> Prefer closest point, don’t insert new vertices.
>
> (Snap to closest point, regardless of it is a node or a segment. No new nodes will be inserted.)

don't seem to work as supposed
[image]

How am I supposed to snap the point to the middle of the line (the real closest point) using this tool ? or am I using the tool wrong and there is something I am not getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of this tool is a bit tricky, indeed. So instead of snapping, better create the closest point on the line layer using QGIS expressions with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)):

```
closest_point( 
     aggregate( 
        'lines',  -- name of your line layer
        'collect',
        $geometry
    )
    ,
    $geometry
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks works great !